# ERROR Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I solve this error:

```
Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component
```

I just try to show activityindicator by using useState hook in react native but i get error

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { Card, Avatar, IconButton } from 'react-native-paper';
import Loading from '../Loader/Loading';

const About = () => {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    
    setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 6000);

  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    {
      loading ? <Loading /> : 

        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>
          <Card style={{ padding: 100, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
            <Card.Title title="About us" subtitle="Our profile"
            left={(props) => <Avatar.Icon {...props} icon="folder" />}
            right={(props) => <IconButton {...props} icon="dots-vertical" onPress={() => {}} />}
            />
            <Text>This is about us page</Text>
          </Card>
          </Text>
        </View>
    };

    </>
  )
}

export default About;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center' 
    }
});
```

This is ActivityIndicator component which is imported on About component

```
import { ActivityIndicator , MD2Colors} from 'react-native-paper'

function Loading(){

    return <ActivityIndicator animating={true} color={MD2Colors.red800} />

}

export default Loading;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example code, there is a `;` after your JSX expression. Remove it and it'll work.

```js
<>
{ /* CODE */ };
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Text element can only contain text nodes or other Text elements.
You cannot nest the Card element inside a Text element.

Either remove the Text parent:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Card style={{ padding: 100, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
        <Card.Title title="About us" subtitle="Our profile"
            left={(props) => <Avatar.Icon {...props} icon="folder" />}
            right={(props) => <IconButton {...props} icon="dots-vertical" onPress={() => {}} />}
        />
        <Text>This is about us page</Text>
    </Card>
</View>
```

Or remove the Card child

Comment: I just removed Text but error still not solved!